# Reordering Treenodes in C#.NET

Tags: ttreenodes

I have a Visual Studio 2005 C#.NET GUI application. I want to provide the flexibility to reorder the treenodes in the treeview just by dragging and dropping them wherever desired. Is that possible by using any property of the treeview class? Or do I have to do it the hard way by writing events for mouseup and then sensing the dragging of the node etc etc. Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks, Viren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's better events than mouseup that make this kind of thing easy. This [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307968) should give you some idea. Read [the documentation for the TreeView events that begin with drag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview_events.aspx) for more info.